# How to mock random.choice in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want `choice` to return the same value `1000` every time in my unittest. The following code doesn't work.

```
import unittest
from random import choice

from mock import mock

def a():
    return choice([1, 2, 3])

class mockobj(object):
    @classmethod
    def choice(cls, li):
        return 1000

class testMock(unittest.TestCase):

    def test1(self):
        with mock.patch('random.choice', mockobj.choice):
            self.assertEqual(a(), 1000)
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in test1
    self.assertEqual(a(), 1000)
AssertionError: 3 != 1000
```

How should I modify it to make it work? I'm using python2.7

Comment: Which python testing framework is that? I'm not aware of "mockobj". 
How is this code not working - what does it do?

Comment: @DannyStaple Sorry for the inconvenience. `mockobj` is just a class that I created, I have added it to the code so you can just run it to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is that `a()` is using an *unpatched* version of `random.choice`.

Compare functions `a` and `b`:

```
import random
from random import choice

def a():
    return choice([1, 2, 3])

def b():
    return random.choice([1, 2, 3])

def choice1000(values):
    return 1000

import unittest.mock as mock

with mock.patch('random.choice', choice1000):
    print('a', a())
    print('b', b())
```

It prints e.g.:

```
a 3
b 1000
```

## Why?

This line is the problem:

```
from random import choice
```

It imported `random` and than stored `random.choice` into a new variable named `choice`.

Later, `mock.patch` patched the original `random.choice`, but not the local `choice`.

Can I patch the local one? Yes:

```
with mock.patch('__main__.choice', choice1000):
    print('a', a())
    print('b', b())
```

Now it prints e.g.

```
a 1000
b 1
```

(I used `'__main__'` because I put this code into the [top-level file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) - it may be something else in your case)

### So what to do?

Either patch everything, or take a different approach. For example, patch `a()` instead of `choice()`.

## Alternative Solution

In this case, where you want to test behaviour of `random` functions, it may be better to use a [seed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed)

```
def a():
    return random.choice([1, 2, 3, 1000])

def test1(self):
    random.seed(0)
    self.assertEqual(a(), 1000)
```

You can't know beforehand what random values will be generated for a certain seed, but you can be sure that they will always be the same. Which is exactly what you need in tests.

In the last example above, I tested `a()` after `random.seed(0)` once and it returned 1000, so I can be sure it will do so every time:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(0)
>>> print (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 1000]))
1000
>>> random.seed(0)
>>> print (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 1000]))
1000
>>> random.seed(0)
>>> print (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 1000]))
1000
>>> random.seed(0)
>>> print (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 1000]))
1000
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what is mockobj from tests but what you can do is.

```
    @mock.patch('random.choice')
    def test1(self, choice_mock):
        choice_mock.return_value = 1000
        self.assertEqual(a(), 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to improve the @Alex response with a full script to better understand and be adaptable to other cases.

```
import random
from unittest import TestCase, mock

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

def get_random_words(): # Simple function using choice
  l = []
  for _ in range(3):
      l.append(random.choice(letters))
    
  return "".join(l)

class TestRandom(TestCase):

   @mock.patch('random.choice') # *(1)
   def test_get_random_words(self, mock_choice):
    
      mock_choice.side_effect = ['A','b','D','Z'] # *(2)
      result = get_random_words()
    
      self.assertEqual(result, 'AbD', 'Does not generate correct string')
```

## Considerations

*(1) For this example, the function is inside the same file, but in case it is in another file you must change the path of the patch
Ex: `@mock.patch('your_package.your_file.your_function.random.choice')`

*(2) For this case, the `get_random_words` function calls `random.choice` 3 times. This is why you must put equal or more items inside `mock_choice.side_effect`. This is because if it has fewer items it will throw the `StopIteration` error.

Comment: +1 for adding an option to stub the function with different values within a loop. Is that achievable with pytest-mock?